# Formalising regular expressions with a complement operation

Tags: regex, coq, agda, idris

I'm  playing with a formalisation of a certified regular expression matcher in Idris (I believe that the same problem holds in any type theory based proof assistant, such as Agda and Coq) and I'm stuck on how to define semantics of the complement operation. I have the following data type to represent semantics of regular expressions:

```
data InRegExp : List Char -> RegExp -> Type where
 InEps : InRegExp [] Eps
 InChr : InRegExp [ a ] (Chr a)
 InCat : InRegExp xs l ->
         InRegExp ys r ->
         zs = xs ++ ys ->
         InRegExp zs (Cat l r)
 InAltL : InRegExp xs l ->
          InRegExp xs (Alt l r)
 InAltR : InRegExp xs r ->
          InRegExp xs (Alt l r)
 InStar : InRegExp xs (Alt Eps (Cat e (Star e))) ->
          InRegExp xs (Star e)
 InComp : Not (InRegExp xs e) -> InRegExp xs (Comp e)
```

My problem is to represent the type of InComp constructor since it has a non-strictly positive occurrence of `InRegExp` due to the usage of `Not`. Since such data types can be used to define non-terminating functions, they are rejected by terminations checker. I would like to define such semantics in a way that it is accepted by Idris termination checker.

Is there some way that could I represent semantics of complement operation without have negative occurrences of `InRegExp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could mutually define `NotInRegExp` which would explain what it means to not be recognised by a regexp (I haven't checked whether this is valid syntax).

```
data NotInRegExp : List Char -> RegExp -> Type where
 NotInEps : Not (xs = []) -> NotInRegExp xs Eps
 NotInChr : Not (xs = [ a ]) -> NotInRegExp xs (Chr a)
 NotInCat : (forall xs ys, zs = xs ++ ys ->
             NotInRegExp xs l
            + InRegExp xs l * NotInRegExp ys r) ->
            NotInRegExp zs (Cat l r)
etc...
```

You should then be able to define a nice decision procedure:

```
check : (xs : List Char) (e : RegExp) -> Either (InRegexp xs e) (NotInRegexp xs e)
```

Comment: Thanks. You're absolutely right! This solution is simple and elegant.

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro FYI, I have fixed a bug in the definition of the `NotInCat` constructor I had defined.

Answer (score 6):

You can define `InRegex` by recursion on `Regex`. In that case, strict positivity is no issue, but we have to recurse structurally:

```
import Data.List.Quantifiers

data Regex : Type where
  Chr  : Char -> Regex
  Eps  : Regex
  Cat  : Regex -> Regex -> Regex
  Alt  : Regex -> Regex -> Regex
  Star : Regex -> Regex
  Comp : Regex -> Regex

InRegex : List Char -> Regex -> Type
InRegex xs (Chr x)     = xs = x :: []
InRegex xs Eps         = xs = []
InRegex xs (Cat r1 r2) = (ys ** (zs ** (xs = ys ++ zs, InRegex ys r1, InRegex zs r2)))
InRegex xs (Alt r1 r2) = Either (InRegex xs r1) (InRegex xs r2)
InRegex xs (Star r)    = (yss ** (All (\ys => InRegex ys r) yss, xs = concat yss))
InRegex xs (Comp r)    = Not (InRegex xs r)
```

We would need an inductive type for the `Star` case if we wanted to use our old definition. The following obviously doesn't work:

```
InRegex xs (Star r) = InRegex (Alt Eps (Cat r (Star r)))
```

However, we can just simply change the definition and make finiteness explicit:

```
InRegex xs (Star r) = (yss ** (All (\ys => InRegex ys r) yss, xs = concat yss))
```

This has the intended meaning and I don't see any drawbacks to it.

Comment: With your definition, `(a|b)*` is interpreted as `(a*)|(b*)` (this is because `xs = concat (replicate n ys)` requires all sub-matches to be identical).

Comment: A problem with this solution is that `All (flip InRegex r) yss` isn't accepted by Idris termination checker. Is there a way to bypass this problem using a similar solution?

Comment: Just get rid of `flip`. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

You could also define this type by recursion on the RegExp plus some inductive datatype for the semantics of Star.

I guess it wouldn't interact as nicely with the built-in pattern matching but it would have the same induction principle.

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow your idea. Are you saying that I should define `InRegExp`as a function of type `RegEx -> Type` and define an inductive type for Kleene star?

Comment: A function of type "List Char -> RegExp -> Type" but yes

Comment: Oops... I mean `List Char -> RegExp -> Type`... :) Thanks for the suggestion.